# Vagrant and virtualbox painfully slow

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vagrant

I'm having serious issues developing my laravel application on my windows machine. I'm running vagrant 1.6.3 and virtualbox 4.3.12 using the default shared folder. This issue just started to pop up recently. My VBox has 2048MB of RAM and uses 2 cpu cores.

This setup is so extremely slow that my application usually times out loading. Sometimes the same page loads in 3 seconds, sometimes it won't load at all.

Shelling out 80 bucks for the VMware plugin is not an option. I tried RSync too but I can't get it to work properly after hours of searching the new.

I also tried disabling the shared folders but that causes massive permission problems when I try to deploy my files with phpstorm.

So what are some options here. I can live with 2-3 seconds load time, but those timeouts are really bugging me and slow me down tremendously. (I have time to check my facebook while the page loads)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out HHVM+hack was the main culprit. I re-provisioned my box with `php-fpm` and it loads a bit faster. Takes about 1-2 seconds instead of the usual 3+. The timeouts stopped happening as well.